# Why cloudinary's public_id or secure_url is not received to display images in the views of RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, cloudinary

Okay, so this is my third day trying to solve this issue by myself, but I think it's about time to ask for help hehe! I couldn't find any documentation that helps me to find a solution, so I'm publishing the problem here to see if I can get some luck!

From the form I can successfully upload images to Cloudinary, but when I attempt to display them on the view, the  tag doesn't include the src attribute and it's url value.

I'm leaving a link to the project/branch at the end of this text, so you can check the code if needed.

**Things I've done:**

1. I've installed gem "dotenv-rails" to add the cloudinary's secret key, name, etc to ".env" file and gitignore it, so the keys are not published on Github witht he rest of the code.

```
# .env
CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://298522699261255:***********************8@Qa1ZfO4syfbOC
```

2. Then I tested the link between the app and cloudinary. First I downloaded a few images:

```
curl https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2889/33773377295_3614b9db80_b.jpg > san_francisco.jpg
curl https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DC1Xyz3XoAAv7zB.jpg > boris_retreat_2017.jpg
```

Then I uploaded them to Cloudinary successfully:

```
# rails c
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("san_francisco.jpg")
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("boris_retreat_2017.jpg")

#Then removed them from my local environment
rm san_francisco.jpg boris_retreat_2017.jpg
```

I used the Cloudinary tag to call the image in a view and pasted inside the image id assigned by Cloudinary:

```
<!-- app/views/articles/index.html.erb -->
<%= cl_image_tag("wwvryof9dfmpnjubaqvz",
      width: 400, height: 300, crop: :fill) %>
```

3. I proceeded to install Active Storage

```
rails active_storage:install
rails db:migrate
```

4. Then I added a few code lines to the following file:

```
# config/storage.yml
cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
  folder: <%= Rails.env %>
```

5. After that I opened the development.rb file and edited the line that sets where to active storage will store stuff:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
# [...]
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

6. To my Article model I added the following:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
end

# AND TO MY ARTICLE CONTROLLER
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if params[:article][:photo].present?
      uploaded_image = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:article][:photo])
      @article.photo.key = uploaded_image['public_id']
    end

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

7. I added the form using simple form to new.html.rb

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
 <%= simple_form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <!-- [...] -->
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <%= f.file_field :photo, as: :file %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <!-- [...] -->
<% end %>
```

8. Finally, I added the image tag to the show.html.rb view this way:

```
<!-- app/views/articles/show.html.erb -->
<!-- [...] -->
<%= cl_image_tag @article.photo.key, height: 300, width: 400, crop: :fill %>
```

After following all those steps, I get the article with the  tag with no src attribute like in this picture: [Img tag displayed in inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chyPS.png)

The picture is uploaded to Cloudinary, but I cant get it displayed on the view. Any idea about solving this issue?

Remember you can checkout my code here: [text](https://github.com/ThePalmeraTech/la-central/tree/article-image)

Thank you!

Hana

Comment: A little side note - dotenv is a pretty outdated approach to handling credentials. Use the built in [encrypted credentials](https://web-crunch.com/posts/the-complete-guide-to-ruby-on-rails-encrypted-credentials) instead.

Comment: As the uploads are done at the server side of your application and the images are successfully uploaded, the `show.html.erb` would also need to be rendered at the server side in order to get the parameters needed in the `<%= cl_image_tag %>` (you may [refer to this sample project](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples))

Comment: Thank you @epasos_573! I'll dive into that sample project and let you guys know if I got to solve the issue.

@max thank you for your observation

Comment: @epasos_573, I didn't get to fix the issue. I have Cloudinary correctly configured in the server, but still the problem with getting the public_id or setting up the controller persists